# Adding new tags to existing xml file results in adding tags in single line using DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have been trying to update the existing XML file by adding new multiple tags. For ex as shown below in the snippet, it works perfectly in local server wherein the same solution doesn't yield the required result in another server. here I am trying to add TestTag3 and TestTag4 to existing xml.

Local server result: This is the expected one and it is working as expected in local

```
<process id="test">
        <TestTag1>Value1</TestTag1>
        <TestTag2>value2</TestTag2>
        <TestTag3>YES</TestTag3>
        <TestTag4>Value4</TestTag4>
</process>
```

Another server result: it should update in new line for every added new tags

```
<process id="test">
        <TestTag1>Value1</TestTag1>
        <TestTag2>value2</TestTag2>
    <TestTag3>YES</TestTag3><TestTag4>Value4</TestTag4></process>
```

Java code:

```
private boolean addNewTag(Node node, String tagName, String tagValue, Document document) {  
        Element ele = document.createElement(tagName);
        if(tagValue!=null){
            ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tagValue));
            node.appendChild(ele);
            return true;
        }else{
            ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
            node.appendChild(ele);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that your Java code would just build the DOM tree which doesn't have any notion of "line" or "linebreak". What you're refering to is the formatting of the DOM tree into text and you didn't show anything related to that. Also, if you notice a difference between machines then make sure that both are running the exact same version of the application and check what the differences are between the environments (e.g. different Java versions or library versions). That should provide you a starting point to find the reason for the difference in results.

Comment: would you possibly let me know how to add new line in java code every time we add new tag to xml

Comment: As I said, your code doesn't directly change any XML _text_ and a DOM neither knows nor cares about "new line". Adding new tags in text only would not be a good idea so what you need to look into is the marshalling process which converts the DOM tree to text. Look for an option to have the marshaller pretty print the XML text which should result in line breaks and nice indentation.

Comment: I figured a way to resolve this. Post updating the code to have proper indentation, now the updated xml has the desired result.